# Find the solution to the inhomogeneous heat equation given a particular solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Consider the PDE $$u_t=Du_{xx}+x+t$$ where $t>0, x \in (0,a)$ and  $u(x,0)=0, u_x(0,t)=u_x(a,t)=0$.

I'm told that a particular solution is given by $$p(x,t)=xt+\frac{t^2}{2}$$ and I'm asked to use this in order to find the solution.

I've tried defining $v(x,t)=u(x,t)-p(x,t)$ where $p(x,t)$ is the particular solution above. Then $v(x,t)$ satisfies $v_t=Dv_{xx}$ but doesn't satisfy the boundary conditions so this doesn't seem to be a very useful approach.

How should I do this?

Comment: The PDE for $v$ gets the new boundary conditions: $v_x(0,t) = u_x(0,t) - p_x(0,t)$ and so on.

Comment: @Winther Does that actually get me anywhere though? $v(x,t)$ will then satisfy the homogeneous heat equation with inhomogeneous boundary conditions, but I don't know how to solve that, so was that just a bad choice of $v$?

Comment: The given choice for $v$ might not be the best then. One idea is to try a test-solution $p = Ax^3 + Bx^2 + C(t)x + D(t)$ and solve for $A,B,C,D$ and fix the free parameters such that the boundary conditions are nice. Something like $p(x,t) = -\frac{1}{6D}x^3 + \frac{a}{4D}x^2 + \frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{ta}{2}$ seems to work.